# htaccess rewrite rule with pattern mataching

Tags: .htaccess

guys I am trying to redirect my request to different url by matching partial url
for example

http://somedomain.com/uploads/ltf/users/2222/z5apl44t4mjwsx0rnh82rkjo68
to 
http://somedomain.com/render/user/image/2222/z5apl44t4mjwsx0rnh82rkjo68

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/ltf/users/(\d+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ [L,NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
 RewriteRule (.*)  http://localserver.webapp/render/user/image/
```

I also try other solution but no success.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `/` here. And why are you using a RewriteCond for this to begin with - instead of doing this check via the RewriteRule pattern?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/ltf/users/(\d+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ also try with this no luck

Comment: And you have verified that the referrer is actually empty?

Comment: how it should be

Comment: Is this a _Yes, I have verified that_, or just an _I assume that should be the case_?

Comment: its just random tries also try like still no luck
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/ltf/users/(\d+)/([a-z0-9]+)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)  http://localserver.webapp/render/user/image/$1